# Apollo resolver chain returning null

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Gone over the docs many times now but I don't think I'm getting it. I have the following (simplified) definitions:

```
type executive {
  executiveName: String,
  office: [office]
}
type office {
  officeName: String,
}
```

It's possible that there are many (thousands) of offices that could be returned, so I'd like to break apart the call between executives and offices so I can show executives first and load offices in the background.
I call my API like so:

```
query {
    executives {
      executiveName
      office {
        officeName
      } 
    }
}
```

Question 1: Would having this hierarchical structure work for this scenario? Is there a better way you can suggest I can structure my query?

I also have the following resolvers:

```
const queryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Query",
  description: "Query entry point for the application",
  fields: () => ({
    executives: {
      type: GraphQLList(executives),
      resolve: (_, __, { dataSources }) => {
        return dataSources.elasticAPI.getExecutives();
      }
    },
    {
      office: {
        type: office,
        name: "office",
        resolve: async (_, { startDate, endDate }, { dataSources }) => {
          const offices = await dataSources.elasticAPI.getOffices(
            startDate,
            endDate
          );
          return offices
        }
      }
    })
  })
})
```

But get the following response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "executives": [
      {
        "executiveName": "Joe Smith",
        "office": null
      }
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Question 2: Why are my resolvers return null? I would have thought that the offices resolver would have returned the information but it is not being recognized by GraphQL.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "*I'd like to break apart the call between executives and offices so I can show executives first and load offices in the background*". The query you've written does load the offices with each executive.

Comment: Why does an executive have multiple (i.e. a list of) `office`? If that was intended, shouldn't the field name be `offices` (plural)?

Comment: "*I have the following (simplified) definitions:*" - you might want to show your actual definitions. It seems you also expect `office` to take some arguments, but we can't tell whether that's a mistake we'd need to point out or just inconsistent simplification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are my resolvers returning `null`? I would have thought that the offices resolver would have returned the information but it is not being recognized by GraphQL.

The `office` field you showed in your desired schema is part of the `executive` type, not part of the `Query` type. Your resolver object needs to reflect that.

Comment: I understand now. I was thinking that all resolvers had to be part of the Query object, instead of being part of a type definition. Thanks for pointing it out!